# how compare two validators for one field?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I must use two validator for one fields:

```
$this->setValidator('number', new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
                    array('model' => 'Data', 'column' => 'number')               )
          );

$this->setValidator('number', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)));
```

now working only secons validators. how can i compare this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$this->validatorSchema['number'] = new sfValidatorAnd(array(
  new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'Data', 'column' => 'number'),
  new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
));
```